# unique indentifiers of new activities in Brightway

Tags: brightway

I want to create a simple activity to add to my ecoinvent database on Brightway2. How can I create a unique identifier to act as the "code" field?

The only way I know to create an activity from scratch is:

```
bw.Database('database_name').new_activity('code')
```

but I need to specify a code, and I would rather have it automatically generated (as when we do a copy of an existing activity). Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the [docs](https://docs.brightwaylca.org/intro.html#activities-and-exchanges), one can read:

> Brightway2 identifies an activity or flow with the MD5 hash of a few attributes: For ecoinvent 2, the name, location, unit, and categories. For ecoinvent 3, the activity and reference product names.

When diving in the `bw2io` code though (specifically the [utils](https://bitbucket.org/cmutel/brightway2-io/src/3390d0f3155133cd05a3e5eed904f36356ede6e1/bw2io/utils.py?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default)), we see this is not actually exact: Brightway generates a unique code as the MD5 hash of the ecoinvent UUIDs for the activity and the reference flow:

```py
In [1] import brightway2 as bw
       import hashlib

       act = bw.Database('ecoinvent 3.3 cutoff').random()
       act['code']

Out[1] '965e4a277c353bd2ed8250b49c0e24ef'


In [2]  act['activity'], act['flow']

Out[2] ('ff086b85-84bf-4e44-b60e-194c0ac7f7cf',
        '45fbbc41-7ae9-46cc-bb31-abfa11e69de0') 

In [3]  string = u"".join((act['activity'].lower(), act['flow'].lower()))
        string

Out[3] 'ff086b85-84bf-4e44-b60e-194c0ac7f7cf45fbbc41-7ae9-46cc-bb31-abfa11e69de0'

In [4]  str(hashlib.md5(string.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest())

Out[4] '965e4a277c353bd2ed8250b49c0e24ef'

In [5]  act['code'] == str(hashlib.md5(string.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest())

Out[5] True
```

Note that this implies you have informed the `activity` and `flow` fields of your activity dataset. You can generate these using the `uuid` library. You could also decide to use other fields in your MD5 hash (e.g. the name of the activity and of the reference flow, as the docs imply).

Comment: thanks @MPa! what the activity and flow fields represent? I tried to find the codes of a random activity in my exchangedataset and activitydataset and I couldn't find them. The documentation on the [schema](https://docs.brightwaylca.org/intro.html?highlight=schema) does not talk about these fields (I guess it's too ecoinvent-specific). Or more simply, how should I generate them with the uuid library?

Comment: They are the unique codes used by ecoinvent, see the activity overview files [here](http://www.ecoinvent.org/support/documents-and-files/information-on-ecoinvent-3/information-on-ecoinvent-3.html). I'm not sure how the UUIDs are created. You can use some fields (e.g. for the activity, you could use activity name, location, start date and end date), concatenate them as one large string and use `uuid.uuid5(uuid.NAMESPACE_DNS, your_string)` to generate a UUID. You are free to do what you want, just make sure the string you feed to the function is unique.